# Reactjs autosuggest - Receive selected items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, jsx, autosuggest

How can I get the selected element when I submit the form. I'm using reactjs autosuggest.

My Parent Component

```
<Form
                 onSubmit={this.submitFormadd}
                 layout="horizontal"
                 ref="myformadd"
                 >
                     <MyAutosuggest
                       data={this.props.users}
                       id="river"
                       name="river"
                       placeholder="Enter River Name"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       required="true"
                     />
                     <MyAutosuggest
                       data={this.props.drivers}
                       id="driver"
                       name="driver"
                       placeholder="Enter Driver Name"
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                     />
                     <fieldset>
                       <Row layout="horizontal">
                           <input className="btn btn-primary" formNoValidate={true} type="submit" defaultValue="Submit" />
                       </Row>
                   </fieldset>
                 </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

```
onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    let bookObj;

    if (method == "click") {
      this.props.bookiesList.filter(book=> {
        if (book.name.trim() === newValue.trim()) {
          bookObj= book
        }
      });
    }

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `onChange` wrongly for the autosuggests. Change:

```
onChange={this.onChange}
```

to

```
onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
```

Then store the selected elements in the `onChange` method. When the submit is triggered, you will have the elements already stored.

Comment: I still do not understand how I will get the selected data when I submit. 
Depending on the input id, we need to pick the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Autosuggest

                   id="river"
                   name="river"
                   placeholder="Enter River Name"
                   onChange={this.onChange}
                   required="true"
                   data={this.props.users}                                                                                                                                                
                   getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue.bind(this)}/>
```

I think the above code would help, in getSuggestionValue, you will get value, which you can use,

for example:

```
getSuggestionValue(value){
     this.setState({ val:value});  //or anything else
}
```

while submitting (example):

```
submitFunction(){
  console.log(this.state.val); //receive value here
}
```

changes in code from [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLrjYp?editors=0010)

```
const languages = [
  {
    name: 'C',
    year: 1972
  },
  {
    name: 'C#',
    year: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'C++',
    year: 1983
  },
  {
    name: 'Clojure',
    year: 2007
  },
  {
    name: 'Elm',
    year: 2012
  },
  {
    name: 'Go',
    year: 2009
  },
  {
    name: 'Haskell',
    year: 1990
  },
  {
    name: 'Java',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Javascript',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Perl',
    year: 1987
  },
  {
    name: 'PHP',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Python',
    year: 1991
  },
  {
    name: 'Ruby',
    year: 1995
  },
  {
    name: 'Scala',
    year: 2003
  }
];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters
function escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

function getSuggestions(value) {
  const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

  if (escapedValue === '') {
    return [];
  }

  const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

  return languages.filter(language => regex.test(language.name));
}

function getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
  return this.props.getValue(suggestion.name,this.props.id);
}

function renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
  return (
    <span>{suggestion.name}</span>
  );
}

class MyAutosuggest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    };    
  }

  onChange = (_, { newValue }) => {
    const { id, onChange } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });

    onChange(id, newValue);
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { id, placeholder } = this.props;
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder,
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <Autosuggest 
        id={id}
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps} 
      />
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  onChange(id, newValue) {
    console.log(`${id} changed to ${newValue}`);
  }
  getValueForInput(val,id){
    console.log(val,id);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyAutosuggest
          id="type-c"
          placeholder="Type 'c'"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          getValue={this.getValueForInput.bind(this)}
        />
        <MyAutosuggest
          id="type-p"
          placeholder="Type 'p'"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Problem 1: I just do not want the value. I need an id for the object.
Problem 2: I use two autosuggest on the same form. How can i solve it?

Comment: solution for problem 1: you will get the whole object in "value"(param of getSuggestionValue)

Comment: solution for problem 2: use different functions for onChange,getSuggestionValue etc for two autosuggests

Comment: I have also used 2 in a page, it was working fine for me! :)

Comment: I have identified a child component ("MyAutosuggest"). I call this twice. How do I do this in the selected item case.

Comment: can you please elaborate, Im sorry, i didnot understand :(

Comment: I am using this code https://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/yoYjoo?editors=0010 But I can not catch the selected elements with the submit on the parent component.

Comment: im editing the answer,(with changes in the code that you have provided ) in codepen

Comment: Does not accept getValue value? And are you sure that it picks up the selected members? :/

Comment: im giving a callback function as a prop to child, whenever the value changes, that prop function is called, so we can get value from child component to parent component and change state accordingly